# Connect to message broker with Spring cloud stream from test

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

There are articles on how to test Spring cloud stream applications without connecting to a messaging system with spring-cloud-stream-test-support. But I want to really connect to RabbitMQ from my integration test, and cannot do that. Here is test class:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@EnableBinding(Source.class)
public class StreamIT {

  @Autowired
  private Source source;

  @Test
  public void testMessageSending() throws InterruptedException {
    source.output().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("test").build());
    System.out.println("Message sent.");
  }

}
```

Everything is the same as in @SpringBootApplication, they use the same properties from application.yml.

But there is no log line that message is sent (`o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Created new connection: SpringAMQP#22e79d25:0/SimpleConnection@5cce3ab6 [delegate=amqp://guest@127.0.1.1:5672/, localPort= 60934]`
),
and even if broker is not started, there is no `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)`.

Am I doing something wrong? What is needed to create real connection to broker and send message from test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

You need to remove the test-support jar from the pom. It's presence (in test scope) is what triggers replacing the real binder with a test binder.

After removing the test binder support, this works fine for me...

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class So49816044ApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private Source source;

    @Autowired
    private AmqpAdmin admin;

    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate template;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        // bind an autodelete queue to the destination exchange
        Queue queue = this.admin.declareQueue();
        this.admin.declareBinding(new Binding(queue.getName(), DestinationType.QUEUE, "mydest", "#", null));

        this.source.output().send(new GenericMessage<>("foo"));

        this.template.setReceiveTimeout(10_000);
        Message received = template.receive(queue.getName());
        assertThat(received.getBody()).isEqualTo("foo".getBytes());
    }

}
```

Although there is not a rabbit sample; there is a [kafka sample that uses a real (embedded) kafka binder for testing](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/testing-samples/test-embedded-kafka), although the test jar is excluded, it doesn't explicitly say that's needed.

Comment: I know what it means, please read the whole question. Ant that message is logged when broker runs on 127.0.0.1

Comment: Oh, sorry, missed that - did you remove the test-support jar from the classpath? That's what forces the test binder to be used.

Comment: Exactly. Put that dependency when started project, thought it would provide additional test utilities, not that it would silently prevent connections to the broker! Please add this as an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: Done; thanks; sorry for the initial confusion - my eyes went straight to the "connection refused".

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using `@SpringBootTest` annotation in your test, Spring Boot will evaluate all available auto-configurations.

If you have `spring-cloud-stream-test-support` dependency in your test classpath then following auto-configurations will be also evaluated:

- `org.springframework.cloud.stream.test.binder.TestSupportBinderAutoConfiguration`
- `org.springframework.cloud.stream.test.binder.MessageCollectorAutoConfiguration`

As a result, you have only one binder in the application context - `org.springframework.cloud.stream.test.binder.TestSupportBinder`. By its name, you can understand that it does nothing about real binding.

Excluding/removing of `spring-cloud-stream-test-support` dependency from test classpath - is a dubious solution. Since it forces you to create two separate modules for unit and integration tests.

If you want to exclude previously mentioned auto-configurations in your test. You can do it as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {TestSupportBinderAutoConfiguration.class, MessageCollectorAutoConfiguration.class})
public class StreamIT {
```